# Angular 4:Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

Trying to learn form handling in angular4 from their [offical doc](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

But i got the following error in console

> Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to
>   "ngForm"

Seems like forms module import issue in angular2 but i've already imported this to my `component.ts file

```
    import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
             CommonModule,
             FormsModule ,
             BrowserModule,
             ReactiveFormsModule     
        ]
    })
   export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible',
            'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];

  model = new Items(18, 'Dr IQ', this.powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet');

  submitted = false;

  onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }          
}
```

In html

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name"  class="form-control" id="name" required>
      </div>

<form>
```

Comment: It looks here like the component is using the module decorator, is that right? Which module declares `FormsComponent`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue

Comment: Solved that issue however i got an another error `If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form`

Comment: Yep, just add the `name` attribute to your `input` tag, like `<input type="text" name="example" />`

Comment: yeah its solved